# wxWidgets c++ MacOS fails to build because memset_s is undeclared

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, cmake, wxwidgets

I'm on macOS 12.4 I have run `xcode-select --install` to install the build tools. I'm using VSCode and my c++ configurations I've added the mac frameworks as.
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks` and `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/` The reason I added this second one is it contains a `string.h` file which contains a declaration for `memset_s`

The error generated is this:

```
/Users/Greeley/Workspace/Cppspace/Culinoire/build/subprojects/Source/wxWidgets_external/src/unix/utilsunx.cpp:229:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'memset_s'
    memset_s(v, n, 0, n);
    ^
1 error generated.
make[5]: *** [libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/unix/utilsunx.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
```

My code is here: https://github.com/Greeley/Culinoire but it's just CMakeLists.txt files right now, and the wxWidgets Hello World as main.cpp also my .vscode directory.

I followed this: this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdHqoyG73Jk
and this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfuBS9n5_aY
And then found this on github with the same issue.
https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/19334

and put the define at the top of main.cpp and put it in the defines array within c_cpp_properties.json however I still get the same error as above.

I really don't understand what's going wrong. I'd greatly appreciate some help.

there's 4 CMakeLists.txt in the project, these are their contents:

/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++")


project(Culinoire LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# ExternalProject base
set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY EP_BASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/subprojects)

set(STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/stage)

add_subdirectory(external)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(${PROJECT_NAME}_core
  DEPENDS
    wxWidgets_external
  SOURCE_DIR
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
    -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}
    -DCMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS=${CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS}
    -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED}
    -DwxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR}
    -DENV_WX_CONFIG=${ENV_WX_CONFIG}
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
  BUILD_ALWAYS
    1
  INSTALL_COMMAND
    ""
  )
```

Edit below: Changed static to 1 and universal to 0
/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++")

project(wx_cmake_template_core LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__)

# hack for buggy CMake's FindwxWidgets script
if (DEFINED ENV_WX_CONFIG)
    set (ENV{WX_CONFIG} ${ENV_WX_CONFIG})
endif()

set(wxWidgets_USE_DEBUG 1)
set(wxWidgets_USE_UNICODE 1)
set(wxWidgets_USE_UNIVERSAL 0)
set(wxWidgets_USE_STATIC 1)
set(wxWidgets_CONFIG_OPTIONS --toolkit=base --prefix=/usr)
set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "/Users/Greeley/Library/wxWidgets")
set(wxWidgets_LIBRARIES "/Users/Greeley/Library/wxWidgets/lib")

find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base REQUIRED HINT ${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR})

set(SRCS main.cpp)

if (APPLE)
    # create bundle on apple compiles
    add_executable(main MACOSX_BUNDLE ${SRCS} )
    # Set a custom plist file for the app bundle - needed for Mac OS Retina display
    set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist)
else()
    # the WIN32 is needed for Windows in order for it to look for WinMain
    # instead of the main function. This is ignored on other systems,
    # so it works on all platforms
    add_executable(main WIN32 ${SRCS})
endif()

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

/external/CMAkeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(wxwidgets)
```

/external/wxwidgets/CMakeLists.txt

```
# check if wxWidgets is already installed in the system - using CMake's built in script FindwxWidgets
find_package(wxWidgets QUIET)

if (wxWidgets_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found preinstalled wxWidgets libraries at ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}")
    add_library(wxWidgets_external INTERFACE)
else()
    message(STATUS "Preinstalled wxWidgets not found.")
    message(STATUS "Will download and install wxWidgets in ${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
    
    include(ExternalProject)
    ExternalProject_Add(wxWidgets_external
        GIT_REPOSITORY
        https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
        GIT_TAG
        3.2
        UPDATE_COMMAND
        ""
        CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX}
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS=${CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED}
        -DwxBUILD_SHARED=OFF
        CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
        TEST_AFTER_INSTALL
        0
        DOWNLOAD_NO_PROGRESS
        1
        LOG_CONFIGURE
        1
        LOG_BUILD
        1
        LOG_INSTALL
        1
        )


    set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR ${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX})
    file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR}" wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR)
    set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR ${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "wxWidgets installation dir")

    set (ENV_WX_CONFIG ${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/wx-config)
    file (TO_NATIVE_PATH "${ENV_WX_CONFIG}" ENV_WX_CONFIG)
    set(ENV_WX_CONFIG ${ENV_WX_CONFIG} CACHE INTERNAL "wx-config dir")

endif()
```

#### EDIT  BELOW

I changed the CMakeLists.txt file to

```
# check if wxWidgets is already installed in the system - using CMake's built in script FindwxWidgets
find_package(wxWidgets QUIET)

if (wxWidgets_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found preinstalled wxWidgets libraries at ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}")
    add_library(wxWidgets INTERFACE)
else()
    message(STATUS "Preinstalled wxWidgets not found.")
    message(STATUS "Will download and install wxWidgets in ${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
    
    include(ExternalProject)
    ExternalProject_Add(wxWidgets
    GIT_REPOSITORY
    https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
    GIT_TAG
    master
    UPDATE_COMMAND
    ""
    CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    -DwxBUILD_SHARED=OFF
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
    TEST_AFTER_INSTALL
    0
    DOWNLOAD_NO_PROGRESS
    1
    LOG_CONFIGURE
    1
    LOG_BUILD
    1
    LOG_INSTALL
    1
)


    set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR ${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX})
    file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR}" wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR)
    set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR ${wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "wxWidgets installation dir")

    set (ENV_WX_CONFIG ${STAGED_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/wx-config)
    file (TO_NATIVE_PATH "${ENV_WX_CONFIG}" ENV_WX_CONFIG)
    set(ENV_WX_CONFIG ${ENV_WX_CONFIG} CACHE INTERNAL "wx-config dir")

endif()
```

The build now completes and wxWidgets is 'found' but then goes to fail because wx/wx.h isn't found

```
-- Found wxWidgets: -L/Users/Greeley/Workspace/Cppspace/Culinoire/build/stage/lib;-pthread;/Users/Greeley/Workspace/Cppspace/Culinoire/build/stage/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.a;/Users/Greeley/Workspace/Cppspace/Culinoire/build/stage/lib/libwx_baseu-3.2.a;-lwx_baseu-3.2;-lwxjpeg-3.2;-lwxpng-3.2;-lwxtiff-3.2;-framework AudioToolbox;-framework WebKit;/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd;-lwxregexu-3.2;/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib/libiconv.tbd;-framework CoreFoundation;-framework Security;-framework Carbon;-framework Cocoa;-framework IOKit;-framework QuartzCore (found version "3.2.0") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Greeley/Workspace/Cppspace/Culinoire/build/subprojects/Build/Culinoire_core
[ 87%] Performing build step for 'Culinoire_core'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
/Users/Greeley/Workspace/Cppspace/Culinoire/src/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'wx/wxprec.h' file not found
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [subprojects/Stamp/Culinoire_core/Culinoire_core-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Culinoire_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: why did you mix 2 things? You said you installed the `command line tools` from XCode, but then you said you arfe using VSCode. Why not use Xcode all the way through? Or just use native gcc and not clang? Anyway - how did you build the library itself and how did you build the `minimal` sample? What version of wxWidgets do you try? Also, I believe you do need to install Xcode as it will install the actual OSX SDK as it is probably missing...

Comment: I can't build the library due to the `memset_s` being undeclared. 
And it's my understanding that in order to use any IDE on mac to write c or c++ code you have to install all the command line tools. otherwise I don't have access to clang or any of the headers.
I have xcode fully installed.

edit: mistakenly thought cmake came from command line tools, but I installed it separately.

Comment: ok. try the following: `cd ~/wxWidgets && mkdir buildOSX && cd buildOSX && ./configure --enable-debug && make -j3 && cd samples/minimal && make && open minimal.app` If you have Xcode installed and command line tools installed without any errors this should complete. What version of wxWidgets do you try to build? And sorry for misunderstanding - I thought you were trying to build your own code.

Comment: I was trying to build my own hello world sample. Building like that worked, the minimal opened, but I still have the same problem when I build the project with cmake. 
The CMakeLists.txt under /external/wxWidgets is supposed to download and build branch 3.2 from github.

When I tried before without the CMake lists, I did everything you said except used `build-cocoa-debug` directory and only did make not make -j3. I followed this https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/plat_osx_install.html.

That worked for building it but VScode still couldn't find it. even after adding to my include path.

Comment: ok, so you are using 3.2.0. now, the error you are asking - does it come from building wxWidgets or your own code/minimal sample? Because building the library itself should use the library CMake configuration. And it should work out the box.

Comment: Can you provide your CMakeList or whatever CMake configuration you are using? Just edit the OP and drop it there...

Comment: There's 4 of them and they're in the GitHub, I'll also edit and add the current wxWidgets one and my main one.

Comment: @Greely, Is there a reason you use `set(wxWidgets_USE_UNIVERSAL 1)` This will create a universal build of the library which is bound to have problems. Use the default OSX build (COCOA). BTW - you don't need to have that many files - just one file should suffice in the top-level directory.

Comment: No I don't have a reason for that, I was just flipping a bunch of those switches trying out different ones. I followed a tutorial for these CMake files. I don't really understand how I would do this all in one. Should I just combine them? I don't really think combining them will change how it executes.

Comment: @Igor I've made some changes and got a new error. Not sure that it's better though, I edited the original post with my changes and the new error. I appreciate all your help this far.

Comment: look at the CMake configuration files in wxWidgets and its `minimal` sample. The library has support for CMake. Try building it using the existing configuration (both library and the sample). See how it goes.

Comment: @Igor no disrespect but how does that help me? We've already established that I can build the library. My latest edit shows that it builds with mine as well. When I use the CMakeLists.txt from wxWidgets's GitHub inside my `/external` folder it's riddled with red squiggles telling me it won't work. 

How do I bring wxWidgets into vsCode so I can use it there with intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

in /src/CMakeLists.txt I added
`include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})`
and changed the project name to reflect my actual project name.

so the entire file looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++")

project(Culinoire LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__)

# hack for buggy CMake's FindwxWidgets script
if (DEFINED ENV_WX_CONFIG)
    set (ENV{WX_CONFIG} ${ENV_WX_CONFIG})
endif()

set(wxWidgets_USE_DEBUG 1)
set(wxWidgets_USE_UNICODE 1)
set(wxWidgets_USE_UNIVERSAL 0)
set(wxWidgets_USE_STATIC 1)
#set(wxWidgets_CONFIG_OPTIONS --toolkit=base --prefix=/usr)

find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base REQUIRED)

set(SRCS main.cpp)

include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

if (APPLE)
    # create bundle on apple compiles
    add_executable(main MACOSX_BUNDLE ${SRCS} )
    # Set a custom plist file for the app bundle - needed for Mac OS Retina display
    set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist)
else()
    # the WIN32 is needed for Windows in order for it to look for WinMain
    # instead of the main function. This is ignored on other systems,
    # so it works on all platforms
    add_executable(main WIN32 ${SRCS})
endif()

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

and my output now is

```
[main] Building folder: Culinoire 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/Greeley/Workspace/Cppspace/Culinoire/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --
[build] [ 50%] Built target wxWidgets
[build] [ 56%] Performing build step for 'Culinoire_core'
[main] Changes were detected in CMakeLists.txt but we could not reconfigure the project because another operation is already in progress.
[build] -- Configuring done
[build] -- Generating done
[build] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/Greeley/Workspace/Cppspace/Culinoire/build/subprojects/Build/Culinoire_core
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable main.app/Contents/MacOS/main
[build] [100%] Built target main
[build] [ 62%] No install step for 'Culinoire_core'
[build] [ 68%] Completed 'Culinoire_core'
[build] [100%] Built target Culinoire_core
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
[cpptools] The build configurations generated do not contain the active build configuration. Using "" for CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE instead of "Debug" to ensure that IntelliSense configurations can be found
```